# How to make Gradle's Zip task tweak compression settings?

Tags: gradle

I am attempting to automate my epub book workflow and I am having an issue with one silly part of the epub spec.  The first file has to be named 'mimetype' and the content of that zip entry has to be uncompressed.

The `ZipOutputStream` class in Java has the needed API to do it (`ZipOutputStream#setLevel`) but I don't see any way to acesses this via the `Zip` task.  Am I out of luck and will I have to do the zip streaming manually, or is there some way to use gradle natively to access the compression profiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a brief look at Gradle (milestone-5) source to find that it's unlikely to be possible.

The only reference to `ZipOutputStream` I found was at line 63 of `org.gradle.api.internal.file.archive.ZipCopySpecVisitor`, and you'll find it's doing this:

```
ZipEntry archiveEntry = new ZipEntry(...);
archiveEntry.setMethod(ZipEntry.DEFLATED);
```

Where `ZipEntry.STORED` is probably what you are looking for, but unfortunately `DEFLATED` appears to be hardcoded. By the way, Gradle appears to be using [Apache commons compress](http://commons.apache.org/compress/) library for handling zip archives.